# How to Administratively assigned 'My Docs folder' to be offline files

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, offline-files

I'd like everyone on a laptop, to be able to take their 'MyDocs' with them - I would like to do this via group policy, but how do I assign a set of files, that is not a drive? If that makes sense.

Some advice would be dearly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My docs is automatically available offline when using offline files. You don't really need to do anything.

Comment: I also assumed that this is the case, but users have reported that their my docs are not available offline. Its only recently that someone told me it's possible to have some settings override that, but I would have assuming that MyDocs offline settings should take precedence over other policies, unless specifically overridden, which I haven't done.

Answer (score 1):

Jason is right, that is the default behavior, but in case someone else has set other options... Your title is worded perfectly as the answer is in it. Using Group Policies, have a look at:

User Configuration> Policies> Administrative Templates> Network> Offline Files

the setting is named **Administratively assigned offline files**

Hope that helps.